# Uniform Convergence practice problem

Tags: real-analysis

Any ideas on how to approach this problem. I did one similar but it was on the interval [0,1]. This question is prep for an exam so no grade is earned, so hopefully someone can't help me out here. The question is,

Show that the sequence:

$$ nxe^{−nx^2}$$

converges uniformly to $0$ on $[a, \infty]$ for every $a > 0$.

I'm having a problem with how to approach. I have been usually taking the derivative and then finding the supremum on the interval. But with this problem we are on an open interval and I am not seeing a way of solving. Any advise or instruction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the maximum of the function $f_n(x)=nxe^{-nx^2}$ goes to zero.

The derivative of $f_n$ is $ne^{-nx^2}(1-2nx^2)$ which has a zero at $x=\sqrt{1/2n}$ which is eventually less than $a$ for any $a>0$. Thus for any $a>0$ there is $n_0$ so that for any $n>n_0$ the function $f_n(x)$ is monotone strictly decreasing on $[a,\infty)$. Its maximum  on $[a,\infty)$ is therefore $f_n(a)$ which converges to $0$.
Thus $$0<f_n(x)\leq f_n(a)\to 0$$

Comment: Thanks. Ok I see to use the A.P. and then the rest follows. Thanks again.